# Count seperate EXCEL cells if value >0

Tags: excel, count, countif

Background:

This excel is to track the hours someone works and what days. It also needs to track the total days worked in a week.

Requirement:

The 'Total Days' column needs to count the Monday(M) to Sunday (S) columns if they are greater than 0

Previously I had a simple COUNTIF(H6:K6, ">0") or whatever it was, which worked well.

Now the user has added in extra columns for pay and charge rates each day, after the corresponding day, which has thrown the formula off, and the COUNTIF formula wont do the columns separately inside the same formula.

[Snippet of excel layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SMsv.png)

Also some clarification, In AZ1 for instance I would want it to count H1, K1, N1, etc up to Z1

If anyone could help me work out a formula, that would be great!

Comment: Soooo change the range to `H1:Z1` and drag down?

Comment: As I said, they have added cells after the days, whose values will also be >0, meaning it is counting those aswell

Comment: So you have groups of ranges?  Then you want `COUNTIFS(H1,">0",N1,">0"...`

Comment: That's what I thought would fix it, but it just shows 0 once I put it in, with the correct cells

Comment: yeah I was driving into work and realized that I was wrong.  @nwhaught has it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Since that didn't work, this should do the trick:

```
=COUNTIF(H5,">0")+COUNTIF(K5,">0")+COUNTIF(N5,">0")+COUNTIF(Q5,">0")+COUNTIF(T5,">0")+COUNTIF(W5,">0")+COUNTIF(Z5,">0")
```

Comment: Same as I said to Scott, I expected that to work, but it just prints 0

Comment: OK, I tried something else in the code. See if that works for you.

Comment: No bug, it's counting instances where H5 AND K5 AND N5 etc are all greater than 0.

Comment: Right.. That makes sense

Comment: Yes! Thats fixed it, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`COUNTIFS` uses `AND` logic, whereas, you need `OR` logic.  Try something like:

`=COUNTIF(A3,">0") + COUNTIF(B3,">0")+...`

Comment: Have an **established user** !

Comment: woot woot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/MOD-function-D64C47F3-AAFD-4B2E-AE5D-C16EE3180576) to determine the stagger of the columns. [SUMPRODUCT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) and [ISNUMBER](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/is-functions-490afee4-fd91-4839-89d4-1257a21b4e25) can take care of the rest.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(MOD(COLUMN(H:Z)-8, 3))*ISNUMBER(H6:Z6))
```